# Distinguish between elements in list of equal divs in JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm learning HTML, CSS and JS with Angular and JQuery at the moment. I have a div "eventBoxes" where you can add as much divs called "eventBox" as you want. Therefore, I have one template of such an eventBox in my HTML file, which i clone, make displayed and add to the div "eventBoxes" when the user wants to add a eventBox.
I now want to get the inputs, that are made in the eventBoxes (one eventBox has several textfields), but obviously they all now have the same id. 
What is a good practice in JS to differ between these same eventBoxes, sothat i can handle each eventBox separately? Do I really have to change the ID's before adding or is there a better way to do so?

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you post some code. In angular you don't often need to reference by id, you use scope. In any case, you shouldn't have multiple elements with the same id - that's not valid html whatever you're using.

Answer (score 0):

If your templating a list then the individual list items should not carry an ID or the ID should also be templated as well in order to avoid duplicate IDs. Event handling on those elements should be performed using the event handler context element. For example if you handle `click` for an `input`, then the context of the `click` event handler would be the specific input that was clicked. Also the `event` object gives you access to specific context for the event like for example `event.target` carries a reference to the specific element the click was performed on.